# MySQL Workbench - Normalizing a List of Data

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, winforms, database-design

## About the Program

Excuse the vague title, but I'm rather new to mySQL and databases. I'm a developer in VB.NET and need to create a program that connects to a database. The program is a guide for a game, and part of the program gives you directions to your next objective when you select a mission. For example, from the application (made in WinForms), you select a "*mission*" from a combo-box control, and a Textbox will populate according to the objectives in the database. A further example could be displayed as this:

You Select "*The First Misson*" from the Combo-Box control.

The Textbox Control now *contains* a **numerical list** of objectives in order, like so:

1. Locate John.
2. John asks you to find a weapon
3. Give the weapon to John
4. Help John fight off the monster
5. John asks you to heal him with a potion
6. Help John reach the portal at the end of the tunnel
7. Speak to John about your rewards

Now, the question is how may I display a list like the one above using a database? I was reading up on *normalization*; however, I still do not see how this may be done.

This is an example of the application (just a mock up, but very similar):

[image]

Now say the user selected a *misson* from the Combo-box located at the top of the application. The application would populate like so:

[image]

## Ideas via Normalization

I understand I could create **two** seperate tables containing data relating to the misson. For example, I might be able to create a **table called "Stages"**, and a **table called "Missons"**, but I see this as inefficient, not to mention populating the database itself would take ages. I quickly found that you could not (obviously) store a list in a single cell. So being just a programmer, and not someone who works with databases, I this is very frustrating.

(If it may help, I can also alter the application in which is retrieving data from the database to allow a list to be displayed a different way.)

## The Overall Issue

There may be "work-arounds" to address this problem, but I don't know what to do. I do not understand how you could display such data using a database. I **understand** how you connect to the database and retrieve data using queries, just not with a list. Also, an elaborate answer would be much appreciated for a newbie at this like me.

Comment: well written, but way too broad.  rather than thinking about data thing about relationships.  like 'there are MANY missions per game'; 'one mission has MANY objectives/stages' etc.  then use google to find tutorials on it (or books).

Comment: I've had this same problem for a while, still havnt figured it out, and Google doesn't help much with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, you seem to be primarily stuck up on database relationships. No worries! When you want a "list" in a database, this means you are looking for a *one-to-many* relationship, or a *many-to-many* relationship. Here is a [brief tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) that explains the differences between these types of relationships.

One of the first steps in database design is to define your entities (i.e. your tables.) In general, your entities will typically be major nouns from your business problem. In this case, you clearly have the following entities (tables): `Mission` and `Objective`. The only other data present on your form is a textbox for mission location and a textbox for mission requirements. Both of these fields can be single properties of the `Mission` table.

The next step is to define your entity relationships. You might define your relationships as follows:

- A `Mission` has one-to-many `Objectives`
- An `Objective` belongs to one `Mission`

Finally, lets list out our known properties:

- A `Mission` has a name (text)
- A `Mission` has one location (text)
- A `Mission` has one requirement (text)

Now we can create a basic database schema. So. What would this look like?

[image]

Each table has it's own [primary key](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-primary-key.htm), denoted by the key image in the picture above. The primary key is a unique identifier for a row of data and is usually represented by an integer. The `Objective` table also has a [foreign key](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.html), the missionID field. This is how the *one-to-many* relationship is defined between these tables.

This way, if we create a `Mission` with missionID 1, we can assign this missionID to many `Objectives`. Just like a list, but in the syntax of a relational database. See the images below:

[image]

[image]

In order to retrieve information about both entities at once, you might use a `JOIN` query. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for elaborate detail and for using my example data. This really helped me understand how to go about this problem. Without the explanations I'd still be on square one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably should read up on *entities* and *relationships*.

Entities are database parlance for things like a `game`, a `mission`, a `requirement`, and a `player` (a person).

Relationships are database parlance for statements like

1. each `game` has one or more `mission`s in it
2. each `mission` has one or more `requirement`s in it, displayed in order
3. zero or  more `player`s can be playing each `game`.

Each *table* in your rdms is a collection of instances of a particular entity. So, you'll have a `requirement` table, for example, that will record the following information for each requirement, each in its own row of the table, for example

```
game_id     the game for which this is a requirement
mission_id  the mission for which this is a requirement
requirement_ordinal  1,2,3,4 etc for which requirement in sequence this one is.
description  the text describing the requirement: "Speak to John about normalizing your rewards."
```

You may declare that a particular combination of the first three items uniquely identifies each `requirement`, which is to say that (`game_id`,`mission_id`,`requirement_ordinal`) is the *primary key* for the `requirement` table.

Desktop apps like MySQL Developer and MS Access have graphic design tools that let you draw this stuff in a charts. Here's a writeup. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81358/05_dev1.htm  This business of entity-relationship modeling can get very elaborate and abstruse, so be careful not to dive in too deep.

Working this all out is what database design is about. I can't design this whole thing for you, but I can offer you some jargon and a conceptual framework to help you figure out how to search for it.